# Can I bend an exhaust flex pipe?

Tags: exhaust, rust, cracking, flex

My exhaust pipe in my 2007 maxima has a crack about an inch outside of a flex pipe, and the repair cost is more than the car is worth to me.

The 2 pipes are totally separate, but right next to each other. I was thinking of buying an exhaust coupler that is slightly bigger on one end, and place the smaller part into the end of the flex pipe, and the larger end over the cracked pipe, and seal it with muffler putty.

Firstly, do you think this will work? My car sounds like a rocket on wheels now and the main objective is to get rid of most of the noise. Emissions isn't a problem for me.

Secondly, the only real way for my to insert the coupler into the flexpipe side, is to slightly bend the flex pipe, a pipes-width width so the I can slide it in. Can I bend it that much or will it break? Keep in mind that the bolts holding the flanges together are completely rusted over.

If you can suggest a enter method of fixing this without welding, I'd be open to that as well.

Comment: are there other rubber mounts you can release to allow one of the sections to move enough to get the part in?

Comment: Nope no rubber mounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, while flexpipe does flex, it is not meant to be flexed more than a very minimal amount, enough to compensate for any vibrations in the exhaust system. I tried very gently to flex it and it only moved a drop, so I went another route because I din't want to bust the pipe.

I fixed my problem by purchasing a Nickson Flat Band Exhaust Clamp at Advance Auto, along with some Hi Temp exhaust sealer putty. Nobody carried the diameter clamp I needed, so I purchased a large one and cut it down to size. After grinding the rust off the cracked exhaust pipes, I coated it liberally with exhaust putty and installed the clamp. I then sealed any little orifices with the putty.

I have been driving my car for a month with this setup, and it is dead silent.

Hope this helps someone else facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this.  i dont know if it would hold.  You could also just put a repair band or exhaust sealing wrap around it.    I couldn't give any better advice without photos

Comment: I wrapped a coke can around (after removing top and bottom) and fixed with two hose clamps - did quite well like 3 days... got the replacement by then .

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple hack-y fixes for exhaust problems, especially since the exhaust system isn't a crucial part of the car and the world won't fall apart if it breaks again.

Personally, I've never had much success with any type of bonding compound.  Since the exhaust heats up considerably, the pipe will expand and contract, which tends to foil any plans relating to compound.  That said, it doesn't hurt to try.  Here are a few other methods that I've found to work better though.

- The can method.  Cut the ends off a can of your choice.  I've heard good things about the Cambell Soup cans -- a bit thicker than your average Coke can, so they'll last better.  Get two metal hose clamps, and clamp the can around the leak in the exhaust. *Voila*!
- What I ended up doing last time was to get a 100A welder from my local Craigslist.  I had never welded before, but it wasn't as hard as I thought.  Not pretty by any means, but it's the exhaust.  Not meant to be pretty.  It was $100 or so, but now I have a welder, and a car that sounds good.  Note that you might still need something to put over any holes.  It's near impossible to patch more than about the thin side of a quarter.

Comment: Do you think a band coupler will work good. The pipes OD is 1.75" but the smallest I can find is 2". Do you think that with a little furnace cement sealant I can fit this on properly or is it too big?